# two identical strings compare not equal

Tags: actionscript-3

something is going wrong:

array dataFromFile is initialized with following code(and indeed when I trace it does output correct file content)"

```
    var dataFromFile:Array;
    var dataLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    dataLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);


    dataLoader.load(new URLRequest("Data.txt"));

    }

    function onLoaded(e:Event):void
    {

        dataFromFile = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
        trace(dataFromFile);
    }
    var dataFromFile:Array;    
    var sectionToLook:String = "[GAME]";

        trace(dataFromFile[i1].toLowerCase());
        trace(sectionToLook.toLowerCase());
        trace("are equal:" + (dataFromFile[i1].toLowerCase() == sectionToLook.toLowerCase()));
trace("the type of data is:" + typeof(dataFromFile[i1]));
    trace("the type of sectionData is:" + typeof(sectionToLook));
```

And the output I'm getting:

[game]

[game]
are equal:false
the type of data is:string
the type of sectionData is:string

How on earth is this possible that two identical strings compare as not equal?

Comment: Two things come to mind: are there any leading/trailing spaces in the file?  Try `trace(":"+dataFromFile[i1]+":")` to check.  Secondly, I don't know actionscript, but does `==` on strings test whether the strings are the same, or whether they are the same object?  Should you be doing something like `dataFromFile[i1].toLowerCase().equals( sectionToLook.toLowerCase() )` ?

Comment: @TripeHound hi, thanks, as it happened there was EOF at the end of each entry. The code for splitting doesn't work as expected and adds EOF to each string which is idiotic really.

Comment: At such occasions - first check the length of those strings. Second - loop through their chars and compare them one by one - sometimes UTF8 failure occurs ;)

Comment: So on each line you had \n\r? (or \r\n, always forgetting :))